# How to use shift to shift $@ one over

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am running a shells script with 3 arguments. I am getting the word count of each one. But I want to skip over the very first argument, maybe by using `shift` or something else.

Most of the examples I've seen using `shift` involve `for/while` loops, which is more than I need for what I'm doing.

The below is within an if-statement, not necessary to show. Is there a simple/quick way to have $@ shift over one?

```
wc $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for((i=2;i<=$#;i++)); do
    wc "${!i}"
done
```

Comment: Note that C-style for loop only works in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93`.

Answer (score 5):

Save the first argument in a variable, then `shift` once:

```
arg1="$1"
shift
wc "$@" >"$arg1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just calling `shift` with argument `1` and remember to quote `"$@"`:

```
shift 1
wc "$@"
```

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work. Something I left out of the title is I am trying to append the results to a file. So I currently am doing: wc "$@" >> $1, but I am getting nothing in there, even with shift 1 before.

Comment: @eltigre: because you have shifted, `$1` is no longer what you enter in command line, you must save it first. If you can provide your full script, we can make it more clearly.